# How to select the desired result in MySQL?

Tags: sql, mysql

setup:

```
create table main(id integer unsigned);    
create table test(id integer unsigned,created datetime,text text);

insert into main value(1);
insert into test value(1,now(),'something1');    
insert into test value(1,now() + interval 1 day,'something2');
```

Using:

```
select main.id, text from main left join test on main.id=test.id
group by main.id where main.id in (1,2,3);
```

returns:

```
+------+------------+
| id   | text       |
+------+------------+
|    1 | something1 |
+------+------------+
```

How to get

```
+------+------------+
| id   | text       |
+------+------------+
|    1 | something2 |
+------+------------+
```

Comment: What do you mean multiple main.id? Please provide examples of input and output, thanks.

Comment: No,can't use limit 1,that way it'll always return one result for maximium.

Comment: Yes,I need multiple entries in the result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following SQL statement:

```
SELECT id, (
    SELECT text
    FROM test
    WHERE test.ID = main.ID
    ORDER BY created DESC 
    LIMIT 0 , 1
    ) AS text

FROM main
```

Edit:

In case you need several columns from table test, you need to add a primary key. Then, in your query, first obtain the primary key column and use it as reference on the following sub queries:

```
# Add the primary key
ALTER TABLE `test` ADD `test_id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY FIRST ;

# Select many columns
SELECT id, (

    SELECT test_id
    FROM test
    WHERE test.ID = main.ID
    ORDER BY created DESC 
    LIMIT 0 , 1

) AS testID, (

    SELECT text
    FROM test
    WHERE test_id = testID

) AS text, (

    SELECT created
    FROM test
    WHERE test_id = testID

) AS created

FROM main
```

Comment: What if I need to get created value at the same time?

Comment: This will be really slow for more records in the table.

Comment: No,it's fast,if I add main.id in (1,2,3),the subquery will be run for 3 time,that's acceptable.

Comment: I tried it in two tables containing 400k and 700k records respectively and it fetches the results in less than a second. Are you sure you're using indices correctly?

Answer (score 0):

**EDITED:**

What about this?

```
select
    main.id, a1.created,a1.text
from
    main
inner join test a1 on
    a1.id = main.id
LEFT OUTER JOIN test a2 ON
    (a1.id = a2.id
    AND (a1.created < a2.created))
WHERE a2.id IS NULL;
```

Comment: Edited, this should be faster. If you know that you need only few records (main.id) you can place where to the first inner join, it can help to make it even more faster.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
        main.id , test.created , test.text 
    FROM 
        main 
        JOIN test ON (main.id = test.id) 
        JOIN (select id,max(created) as created from test group by id) as t2 ON (test.id = t2.id and test.created =t2.created)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
select id, text from main left join test on main.id=test.id order by created
```

You may need to use ASC(ending) or DESC(ending)

Comment: No,I ONLY want to select the text with latest created time.

Comment: actually one more thing, the limit 1 that Rax mentioned is needed since you want just the latest (or is that what you meant by your comment)